# C# UserControl - A circular control reference has been made

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to access fdtlc.Controls instead of fdtlc.flpFlightList.Controls

```
public partial class FlightDetailListControl : UserControl
{
    public ControlCollection Controls //Error circular control reference has been made
    {
        get
        {
            return flpFlightList.Controls; // flpFlightList is a FlowLayoutPanel
        }
    }


    public FlightDetailListControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlightDetailListControl and FlowLayoutPanel are both Controls, so they both already have a ControllCollection named Controls inherited from UserControl. You'll have to pick another name for your property in FlightDetailListControl.

Comment: i don't know why it didn't work last time i rename property Controls in FlightDetailListControl (may be i should rebuild it). but it's work now.

Thank you.